# Wrap C++ lib with Cython

Tags: python, cython

I'm new to Cython and I'm trying to use Cython to wrap a C/C++ static library. I made a simple example as follow.

**Test.h:**

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

int add(int a, int b);
int multipy(int a, int b);

#endif
```

**Test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;

}

int multipy(int a, int b)
{
    return a*b;
}
```

Then I used g++ to compile and build it.

```
g++ -c test.cpp -o libtest.o
ar rcs libtest.a libtest.o
```

So now I got a static library called `libtest.a`.

**Test.pyx:**

```
cdef extern from "test.h":
        int add(int a,int b)
        int multipy(int a,int b)

print add(2,3)
```

**Setup.py:**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension("test",
                     ["test.pyx"],
                     language='c++',
                     include_dirs=[r'.'],
                     library_dirs=[r'.'],
                     libraries=['libtest']
                     )]

setup(
  name = 'test',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

The I called:

```
python setup.py build_ext --compiler=mingw32 --inplace
```

The output was:

```
running build_ext
cythoning test.pyx to test.cpp
building 'test' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win32-2.6
creating build\temp.win32-2.6\Release
C:\Program Files\pythonxy\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -I. -IC:\
Python26\include -IC:\Python26\PC -c test.cpp -o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\test.o
writing build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\test.def
C:\Program Files\pythonxy\mingw\bin\g++.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -static --entry _D
llMain@12 --output-lib build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\libtest.a --def build\temp.w
in32-2.6\Release\test.def -s build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\test.o -L. -LC:\Python
26\libs -LC:\Python26\PCbuild -ltest -lpython26 -lmsvcr90 -o test.pyd
g++: build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\libtest.a: No such file or directory
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

I also tried to use `libraries=['test']` instead of `libraries=['libtest']`. It gave me the same errors.

Any clue about this?

Answer (score 29):

If your C++ code is only used by the wrapper, another option is to let the setup compile your .cpp file, like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension("test",
                     ["test.pyx", "test.cpp"],
                     language='c++',
                     )]

setup(
  name = 'test',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

For linking to a static library you have to use the [extra_objects](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html) argument in your `Extension`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension("test",
                     ["test.pyx"],
                     language='c++',
                     extra_objects=["libtest.a"],
                     )]

setup(
  name = 'test',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

Comment: No, I made 'test.cpp' only for testing. In the real project, I only have a head file and a static library.

Comment: It seems like what you want is the `extra_objects` option, edited answer.

Comment: @zyq So how do we continue once the .so file has been created?

Comment: @LuperRouch Then what is the next step with the .so?

Comment: @Dualinity: you import it like any normal python module (`import test` in my example)

Comment: Wow, that's great :) I tried to load the name of the .so and many variations.

Answer (score 5):

Your `Test.pyx` file isn't doing what you expect.  The `print add(2,3)` line *will not* call the `add()` C++ function; you have to explicitly create a wrapper function to do that.  Cython doesn't create wrappers for you automatically.

Something like this is probably what you want:

```
cdef extern from "test.h":
        int _add "add"(int a,int b)
        int _multiply "multiply"(int a,int b)

def add(a, b):
    return _add(a, b)

def multiply(a, b):
    return _multiply(a, b)

print add(2, 3)
```

You can look at Cython's [documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/external.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can fix this specific problem by specifying the right `library_dirs` (where you actually **put** libtest.a -- apparently it's not getting found), but I think then you'll have another problem -- your entry points are not properly declared as `extern "C"`, so the function's names will have been "mangled" by the C++ compiler (look at the names exported from your libtest.a and you'll see!), so any other language except C++ (including C, Cython, etc) will have problems getting at them. The fix is to declare them as `extern "C"`.

Comment: Where should I declare extern "C"? However, i think the problem now is that the build complains it can't find libtest.a instead of one of the function, i.e. add() or mulitpy(). So I'm not sure whether this will work.
It is quite weird to me that it complained there is no libtest.a in 'build\temp.win32-2.6\Release'. Isn't that the build folder generated by Cython itself? Why did Cython try to look for the libtest.a there?

Comment: `extern "C"` goes in the functions' declarations in the `.h`, and as I said that's the next problem you'll face after you fix the incorrect `library_dirs` (you say libraries are "in the current directory" and the `Release` one happens to be the current directory at the time the compiler/linker is looking for the library).