# Cython unable to find C functions and object from external C file

Tags: python, cython

Right now I am trying to load C functions using Cython into Python, similar to what is described here: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html. Let's say my C file is called temp.c, my pxd file is called decl.pxd, and my pyx file is called test.pyx. Let's say I have a function I am trying to import from temp.c called `int my_func(int spam)`:

```
cdef extern from "temp.c":
 int my_func(int spam)
cdef int my_func(int spam)
```

I then cimport my_func into test.pyx and try to use it:

```
from decl cimport my_func

my_func(1)
```

Cython compiles this fine, but then when I try to import the "test" module built from test.pyx using the Python shell, it throws an error and says "symbol my_func not recognized". Furthermore, when I look at the html file that is generated by the Cython compiler where you can view the C code that is generated for test.pyx, the code from the C file for `my_func` is not there, showing that Cython must have been unable to find `my_func`.

I realize that I haven't gone into much detail about what temp.c looks like, but is there a way I can debug for why Cython is apparently unable to find the source code for `my_func`?

Comment: It's called test.pyx, not temp.pyx.

Comment: http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#configuring-the-c-build. Section beginning "If you have some C files..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a follow up, I solved this problem by compiling temp.c into libtemp.so, and then followed the directions here to link Cython with temp.h (the header file here) and libtemp.so:

[Wrap C++ lib with Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105508/wrap-c-lib-with-cython)

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#implementing-functions-in-c

Note that it says `cdef extern from "spam.c":` should be in .pyx and `cdef void order_spam(int tons)` in .pxd. In your case you've put both in .pxd which seems wrong. Docs also state that function must be static.